# Scan a custom ID using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I have followed [this](http://mrgott.com/swift-programing/34-building-a-barcode-and-qr-code-reader-application-for-ios-using-swift-4-pt1) to learn how to scan qr code, barcode, etc. Basically we can specify the inbuild structure we need to scan.

Now I want to make this detect any custom ID (say my college id) so that I can extract name, address, student_unique_id ,etc. Is there any good tutorial or code base with which I can proceed?

Comment: Asking for off site resources such as tutorials is off-topic on StackOverflow. show what you have tried already and explain any issues with it and we will try to help.

Comment: I want to know how can I scan a custom id to extract things out but I couldn't find anything which I could have used. I don't even know how to do it, that's what I am asking.. my bad if its against the rules

Comment: Most similar questions normally get alot of downvotes and put on hold as its very broad. Scanning a QR code is actually quite specific. its a standard thing always presented in the same way and parsed the same way. Handing a custom ID may need to train a machine learning model to recognise different ones and know the expected location of the details